# Migration Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having a problem migrating my Chrome extension to version 3 of the manifest, in version 2 I have a background.js file and a runtime.js file that is from Chrome, but in the v3 version it only accepts one file.

Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

manifest.json version 3

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.1.7",
  "description": "...",
  "icons": {
    "128": "assets/logo128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"

  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "assets/logo.png"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "*://localhost/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

manifest.json version 2

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.1.8",
  "description": "...",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "assets/logo128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js",
      "runtime.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "assets/logo.png"
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "*://localhost/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

background.js

```
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpXhrBackend} from "@angular/common/http";

const http: HttpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpXhrBackend({build: (): XMLHttpRequest => new XMLHttpRequest()}));

let host: string = 'http://localhost:8888';

console.log('start');

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(request, sender, sendResponse);
  const settings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settings') || '{}');
  if (settings?.server?.local?.host && settings.server.remote.host) {
    host = `http://${settings.server.local.host}:${settings.server.local.port}`;
  }
  console.log(settings, request, sender, sendResponse);
  const handleResponse = (err: HttpErrorResponse | null, data: any) => {
    request.body = err ? {error: err.error.error} : data;
    sendResponse(request.body);
    console.log(err ? err.error : data);
  };
  if (request.message === 'certs') {
    http.get<any>(`${host}/api/sign/certificates`).subscribe(data => handleResponse(null, data), err => handleResponse(err, null));
  }
  if (request.message === 'sign') {
    http.post<any>(`${host}/api/sign/files`, request.body).subscribe(data => handleResponse(null, data), err => handleResponse(err, null));
  }
  if (request.message === 'certificate') {
    http.get<any>(`${host}/api/certificate?thumbprint=${request.body.thumbprint}`).subscribe(data => handleResponse(null, data), err => handleResponse(err, null));
  }
  if (request.message === 'version') {
    sendResponse({
      type: 'success',
      version: chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: 1) Service worker doesn't have XMLHttpRequest, you must use `fetch` instead or put this part of the code inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/). 2) Open chrome://extensions page and click `Errors` for your extension.

Comment: I left the background.js file very simple, my impression is that the file is not being loaded, in version 2 I need to add runtime.js for it to work

background.js

Comment: Yes, it's not loaded. My comment explains why it doesn't work.